# HighChart Solid gauge with two series and different range

Tags: highcharts

I would like to show Thermo and Humidity meter on solid gauge. Problem is that they have different range.

Thermo -15 to 40 celsius 
Humidity 0 to 100 %

Is it possible to build one solid gauge where they are shown?

**EDIT**

I've spent few hours on this and this is what I have http://jsfiddle.net/1ttsant0/6/

```js
$(function () {

    var gaugeOptions = {

        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge'
        },

        title: null,

        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '90%'],
            size: '140%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: {
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    y: 5,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // The speed gauge
    $('#container-speed').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: [{
          stops: [
                [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
            ],
            min: -20,
            max: 30,
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorTickInterval: null,
            tickPixelInterval: 400,
            tickWidth: 0,
            title: {
              text: 'Temperature',
                y: -85
            },
            labels: {
              x: 0,
                y: 16
            }
        }, {

            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorTickInterval: null,
            tickPixelInterval: 400,
            tickWidth: 0,
            title: {
              text: 'Humidity',
                y: -70
            },
            labels: {
                x: 18,
                y: 15
            }
        }],

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            stops: [
                [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
            ],
            data: [45],
            yAxis: 0,
            dataLabels: {
             x: 0,
              y: -10,
              allowOverlap: true,
              format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color: black">{y}  °C</span></div>'
            },
            innerRadius:'70%',
            radius: '100%'
        }, {
            name: 'Humidity',
            data: [100],
            yAxis: 1,
            allowOverlap: true,
            dataLabels: {
             x: 0,
              y: 5,
              format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:15px;color: gray;">{y} %</span>'
            },
            innerRadius:'60%',
            radius: '70%'
        }]

    }));

    // The RPM gauge
    $('#container-rpm').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            title: {
                text: 'RPM'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'RPM',
            data: [1],
            dataLabels: {
                format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span><br/>' +
                       '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">* 1000 / min</span></div>'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' revolutions/min'
            }
        }]

    }));

    // Bring life to the dials
    setInterval(function () {
        // Speed
        var chart = $('#container-speed').highcharts(),
            point,
            newVal,
            inc;

        if (chart) {
            point = chart.series[0].points[0];
            point1 = chart.series[1].points[0];
            inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 10);
            
            newVal = point.y + inc;
            if (newVal < -35 || newVal > 45) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }
      //point.update(newVal);
            
            newVal = point1.y + inc;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 100) {
                newVal = point1.y - inc;
            }
            point1.update(newVal);
        }
    }, 2000);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

<div style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
    <div id="container-speed" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
    <div id="container-rpm" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
</div>
```

**There is still few problems:**

1. Top temperature (40) ends too soon, is it possible to rescale it?
2. Data labels are a bit weird, they should be in this order [-20, 0, 100, 60] instead Temp max and himidity max are mixed
3. Is it possible to show custom data label for 0 Celsius and 45 and 55 humidity?
4. Is it possible to show 1px border between two series?

Comment: With a solid gauge, how would you separate the two values? The fill would be on top of one another...?

Comment: Doesnt really matter I guess, so far I found how to add two series into solidgauge, but that doest solve all my problems